# Did Itachi appear during episode 55 in Chuunin exams

Tags: naruto

Today, while watching Naruto episode 55, where the hokage and some other kages were meeting with the shinobis about Orochimaru, I saw a strange thing:

[image]

Look at the right side of Kakashi, there appears a man who looks like Itachi. Moreover his eyes are hidden which makes him even suspicious.

Is the man really Itachi? If he is, then what he is doing there? Or else who is he?

Comment: Naruto is famous for Easter eggs and characters that shouldn't be there in particular scenarios. For e.g. https://aminoapps.com/c/naruto/amp/blog/easter-eggs-in-naruto-that-you-might-have-missed/V8D3_1QT7u38DK5D8rWqVa4VleW5o4XDq1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no information about who that is, but I can't believe it's Itachi.  Itachi is infamous, especially in the Hidden Leaf village.  I can't imagine him walking into a meeting with Kakashi, other Leaf ninja (with presumably other jonin) and a couple of Kage and not get recognized.

> For example, when Itachi shows up in the Hidden Leaf later in the series, he's instantly recognized by multiple ninjas who attempt to stop him.

In all likelihood, it's just a generic Leaf ninja that the animators happened to make resemble Itachi.

Comment: I don't doubt the shinobi depicted isn't Itachi, there's no reason for him to be there but would it be worth finding the relevant scene in the manga to see what Kishimoto actually put there?

Comment: @Gatchwar That would be a good addition, but I don't know how to even begin trying to find that. :(

Comment: I found the relevant panels, they're on ch 93 pg 5-7. It seems like a gathering of Konoha's jonin but the aforementioned ninja is not present in the few panels showing the group's faces. The manga and anime have somewhat different depictions of who's present. Asuma, Kurenai, and Might Guy all show up in the anime but are nowhere to be seen in the manga. The only recognizable characters in the manga are Kakashi, Anko and the replacement proctor for the third exam. If you like you can include screencaps of the manga to show that an Itachi lookalike wasn't even intended to be there

Comment: @Gatchawar [Naruto is famous for Easter eggs and characters that shouldn't be there in particular scenarios](https://aminoapps.com/c/naruto/amp/blog/easter-eggs-in-naruto-that-you-might-have-missed/V8D3_1QT7u38DK5D8rWqVa4VleW5o4XDq1). Later in the fourth ninja war arc, the animators became quite lazy and began to draw generic characters and in some case, even faces are not drawn properly.